# How to remove or edit Android Limit amount of sms

Tags: java, android, sms, limit

First of all, sorry for my english.

I'm doing an app that needs to send more than 100 sms per hour. But when I send more than 100, i get a lot of pop ups saying **"MyApp is sending a large number of SMS messages. Do you want to allow this app to continue sending messages".**

**Is any way to remove/change it by java code?** I have been looking a lot but all the responses seems to be obsoletes because the most part of them are from android 2.3 or similar. I have root my device and tried to install the app **"SMS Limit Unlock"** but it doesn't work.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks for all.

Comment: on which os are you testing?

Comment: A tablet with android 5.0.2 and in the emulator of eclipse that is using 4.2.2

Comment: Do you also getting message in 4.2.2?

Comment: Yes, in all the os that i try

Comment: Nobody has a solution?

Comment: I believe this is OS level implementation and you can't do anything about it.

Comment: This is not the OS level implementation, The app "SMS Limit Unlock" works for most users (see the ratings and read the reviews) but the question is HOW.

Comment: Does anybody solve this? I want to do this also.